# Bike pedals not moving for upright position

Tags: pedals

I need the help with my bike. When starting a bike (stopped position), I cannot move my pedals to the upright (power) position before starting. When I stopped in the traffic light, I need to move my bike to return my pedal to the upright position. I wanted to ask if it is normal for some bikes or there is a problem with the bike.

[image: I suppose it is not fixie]

I suppose it is not fixie. Correct me if I am wrong. Is it possible to get it changed?

Comment: what kind of brakes does the bike have? could you post a photo? As new user, you'll only be able to post a link, but someone else will be able to edit the question to embed it for you

Comment: Thanks a lot, Paul. You can find the picture of the brake.

Comment: Normal for some bikes.

Comment: The picture shows the front brake. Please make a photo of the rear brake and the rear sprockets (chainwheels).

Comment: On any bike you should be able to pick up the rear wheel move the pedal forward and get the pedal where you would like it. On a bike with a freewheel you should be able to move the pedal backwards and get the pedal where you would like it. Assuming you have a freewheel what happens if you pedal backwards? Does the chain go slack? Does the bike move backwards? Other?

Comment: Most likely, you have to pedal backward to get the pedals in your favourite position. If that is not possible, please post a picture of the rear wheel.

Comment: Could you please add a clear photo of your bike, from the right-hand side, so we can see the whole thing?

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't mention that you don't have a fixie where this wouldn't be possible anyway, if your bike's rear brake has a back-pedalling aka coaster brake, turning the crank backwards is indeed not possible. It is system-inherent.

Answer (score -1):

More information about the above posts are needed, please.
Looks like a coaster brake to me in the picture

[image]

Comment: That looks like a chain guard to me.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider editing, your answer to explain how the existence of a coaster break impacts the ability to return the pedal to an upright position after stopping. A short, one-line answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.